# Classes And Recompilation

Tags: c++, abi

If a class interface doesn't change, but its implementation changes,
(and accordingly the library file containing the class' functionality code) does the client code (driver app) need to be recompiled?

If the driver application doesn't require to be recompiled after the mentioned change, how would the executable file locate the new location of the edited method in the new library (the one containing the new class' edited functionality)?

Comment: http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++ <- interesting info

Comment: I'm no expert, but as far as I am aware it varies. Statically linked libraries (.lib) are bundled inside the executable so this would mean anything using the library requires recompilation (well, just linking) again. Dynamically linked libraries (.dll) keep the files separate, providing the interface is the same it would be a matter of swapping the .dll in the executable folder.

Comment: This depends on your linking policies as mentioned. If you're exposing an interface from a shared library, it might work without recompilation, if you're using a statically linked library, you'll need at least to relink the app.

Comment: @JimmyThompson The DLL file would change if we change the implementation. If the code is not recompiled, the location of the class' function would change (obvious), and therefore we are referencing a wrong entry point (the location of functions/methods is written in the export table, which is in the executable file). I'm really confused and I'm sure that there are many things I don't understand about DLLs. Clarification would be very helpful.

Comment: Never mind. Lightness Races in Orbit answered my last comment. (Dynamic Linking)

Comment: I found an excellent book about this subject(linkers, loaders, libraries and object file formats) [Linkers And Loaders - Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Linkers-Kaufmann-Software-Engineering-Programming/dp/1558604960/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1388216157&sr=8-1&keywords=Linkers+And+loaders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a class interface doesn't change, but its implementation changes, (and accordingly the library file containing the class' functionality code) does the client code (driver app) need to be recompiled?

Generally speaking, no. If you don't break the ABI, then there is no need.

> how would the executable file locate the new location of the edited method in the new library

The same way it did in the old library: the [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) sorts it out for you as your executable boots up.

Comment: Aren't reference locations determined at link time? I don't understand the "runtime linker" part.

Comment: @AdamSharafeddine: If you have a shared library, then [dynamic linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) must be performed when your application boots up. You can't do it during build, because you may not have access to the library file at that time, and you may not even be on the same machine! Dynamic linking is the entire purpose of shared libraries.

Comment: @AdamSharafeddine: I suggest reading up about shared libraries, how they work, and how they're used.

Comment: @Adam Sorry, I don't have any suggestions to hand.

Comment: Here what is going in my mind: If I want to add a new class to the library (that would NOT break Binary Compatibility), how would the runtime linker know about it, in other words, this new class is not present in the .lib file, so how would the runtime linker know about it, and locate it at runtime?

Comment: @AdamSharafeddine: Adding a new class _does_ break binary compatibility. Assuming it has members (and, possibly, ready-made instances) you have new symbols. For precisely that reason, the scenario you just mentioned _is_ problematic. Basically the only thing you can do safely is to alter the body of a function definition, though I have a better list somewhere.

Comment: Your comments really helped to be honest, but still, got some headache.

Answer (score 2):

The ABI is very much dependent on compiler vendor and version. You might get away with not rebuilding the driver application but you have to be really really careful. Define your interface with pure virtual members/functions and no data whatsoever, preferably in a separate include which you do not touch at all.

The .dll or .so file (or equivalent) has to be replaced in the loaded module either by hard file moving or by changing the reference to where the dynamic linker will look for .dll/.so files. On unix/linux commonly an environment variable named LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: So, an abstract class is a requirement to avoid rebuilding the application? Is this the way companies update their software without re-installing? Sorry, but I'm new to libraries!

Comment: It's not a requirement, but from a design perspective they make it easier to alter your code without altering the interface.

Comment: @AdamSharafeddine: No it is not a requirement. The suggested method is very much the 'Solving by avoiding' way, and there is of course the 'Solving by understanding it all' way. You may decipher the object layout of the two different implementations and decide if they are sufficiently compatible, but that is inherently difficult if not impossible.

Comment: I might add I do this frequently when developing and testing some piece of new software. Switching between actual implementation versions and mocked versions by altering which .so files I use, keeping the interface abi-stable all the way. I then have a set of lib-folders for the tests at hand and select implementations by altering the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.